# Is mulesoft have hMail server concept? + Advantages of hMail server

Tags: mule, mule-esb, hmail-server

I want try to implement the ***hMail*** server concept in Mule. Before that i want to know What are all the advantages in ***hMail*** server compare with other Mail servers?

Can anyone suggest me on this?

And Share me if mulesoft have that feature or not?

**Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to connect to hMail and not "implement" hMail. If my understanding is correct then Yes Mule can make it "easy" to connect to mail servers.

A good starting point will be reading about the [Email connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/email-connector) and [SMTP connectors](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.5/smtp-transport-reference)

> "What are all the advantages in hMail server compare with other Mail
>   servers?"

Is probably a separate question cause it's orthogonal to Mule.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply Mrs. Sudarshan. Commonly - What are all the advantages in hMail server compare with other Mail servers? - Can anyone suggest me on this?